# Using timer to get Excel title

Tags: excel, vb6

I have following code to get title of current opened excel file this code working fine. I use timer to every 10 seconds if title change then add new title in list1.

So question is there any method or event to detect if title change then my code work otherwise it not work not check. timer check every 10 seconds my pc work slow if I run this code

```
Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Sub ListWins(Optional Title = "*", Optional Class = "*")
    Dim hWndThis As Long

    hWndThis = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)

    While hWndThis
        Dim sTitle As String, sClass As String
        sTitle = Space$(255)
        sTitle = Left$(sTitle, GetWindowText(hWndThis, sTitle, Len(sTitle)))

        sClass = Space$(255)
        sClass = Left$(sClass, GetClassName(hWndThis, sClass, Len(sClass)))

        If sTitle Like Title And sClass Like Class Then
            Debug.Print sTitle, sClass
            List1.AddItem (sTitle)
        End If

        hWndThis = GetWindow(hWndThis, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Wend
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    ListWins "*.xls*"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `No`. AFAIK, No there is no event as such in vb6 which will trap the title change in Excel or any other window. Also unfortunately 10 second timer might not be good. What happens if the title changes every 2 seconds? It will not retrieve all the titles

However try this alternative which does not use the Timer Control. See if your pc is still slow...

```
Sub Sample()
    '
    ' ~~> Rest of your code
    '

    Wait 2 '<~~ Wait for 2 seconds

    '
    ' ~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks sidhart but my problem is still remain any alternate solution

Comment: sidhart please explain me more your alternative

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Excel COM API to do this. Unfortunately, there is no way of getting the Excel window title - but you could easily manufacture it by appending " - Microsoft Excel". Use the FullName property if you want the complete path.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_oApplication               As Excel.Application

Private Sub Command_Click()

    ' Get a reference to the FIRST instance of the Excel application.
    Set m_oApplication = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

End Sub

Private Sub m_oApplication_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Excel.Workbook)
    List1.AddItem Wb.Name
End Sub

Private Sub m_oApplication_WorkbookAfterSave(ByVal Wb As Excel.Workbook, ByVal Success As Boolean)
    'List1.AddItem "WorkbookAfterSave: " & Wb.FullName
    List1.AddItem Wb.Name
End Sub

Private Sub m_oApplication_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Excel.Workbook)
    List1.AddItem Wb.Name
End Sub
```